# Оператор присваивания и swap

Tags: c++

Есть такая реализация оператора присваивания

```
Matrix & Matrix::operator =(const Matrix& m2) {
if (this != &m2) {
    (Matrix(m2)).swap(*this);
}
return *this;
}
```

И функции swap:

```
void Matrix::swap(Matrix & x) {
std::swap(x.matrix, matrix);
std::swap(x.columns, columns);
std::swap(x.rows, rows);
}
```

Вопрос, почему оператор присваивания принимает объект по ссылке, как и функция swap, т.е. как я понимаю в процессе работы например такого кода:

```
Matrix A,B;
A=B;
```

В качестве параметра для оператора присваивания будет передан B, а в функцию swap А, как итог произойдет обмен значениями, но разве объект B при этом не испортится, ведь его передают по ссылке

Comment: Объект `B` в этом коде не передается в функцию `swap`. Поэтому "испортиться" он никак не может.

Comment: Является ли такая операция присваивания эффективней, чем реализация с поэлементным присваиванием без функции swap? Т.е. мы создаем копию объекта, для которой вызываем swap. Насколько затратна эта операция?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В передаче по ссылке ничего плохого нет. Совсем не обязательно, что объект испортится, если его передать по ссылке в какую-то функцию. Более того, если его передать по `const` ссылке, то он гарантированно не изменится. Зато при передаче объекта по ссылке мы экономим на его копировании. (Не вызываем конструктор копирования, как при передачи по значению).

> В качестве параметра для оператора присваивания будет передан B, а в
>   функцию swap А

Всё верно. В оператор присваивания действительно будет передан B по ссылке. И даже будет передан по константной ссылке, что гарантирует неизменяемость этого объекта внутри функции. 
А в функцию swap будет передан действительно объект A по ссылке, но вот функция swap будет вызвана не у объекта B, а у его копии. Так как вызовем мы её у объекта `Matrix(m2)`. То есть мы создадим новый объект `Matrix` с помощью конструктора копирования. И обмениваться значениями будет объект A  с этой копией, что, разумеется, никак не повлияет на исходный объект B.

Comment: Является ли такая операция присваивания эффективней, чем реализация с поэлементным присваиванием без функции swap? Т.е. мы создаем копию объекта, для которой вызываем swap. Насколько затратна эта операция?